# Filter groups using a condition for each group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following two data frames of user events:

data.favorite (*user* favorited *item* at *time*)

```
           user   item   time   event
1             1      A      2     fav
2             1      B      6     fav
3             2      D      9     fav
4             3      A      5     fav
```

data.view (*user* viewed *item* at *time*)

```
           user   item   time   event
1             1      A      1    view
2             1      A      3    view
3             1      B      4    view
4             1      B      5    view
5             1      B      7    view
6             1      C      8    view
7             3      A      2    view
8             3      A      9    view
```

I now only want to keep those events of data.view that occured after that user favorited that item. E.g. row 1 of data.view would be removed, as user 1 favorited item A at 2. The view event at time 3 however would remain, as the user had already favorited the item at that point. So, the result for this example should look like this:

```
           user   item   time   event
1             1      A      3    view
2             1      B      7    view
3             3      A      9    view
```

My current approach is way too slow. I apply a custom function to data.view:

```
wasFav = function(u, i, t) {
  favs = data.favorite %>% filter(user == u, item == i, time < t)
  return(nrow(favs) > 0)
}
```

Any ideas for a faster approach?

Comment: Look for 'data.table non-equi join' and I believe you find nice, relevant relevant examples on SO and elsewhere. E.g. `d.fav[d.view, on = .(user, item, time < time), nomatch = 0]`.

Comment: @Henrik, you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `match` with data.frames called data.view and data.fav:

```
#Find indices of matching users&items
Indices <- match(paste(data.view$user, data.view$item), paste(data.fav$user, data.fav$item))

#add corresponding fav time to data.view:    
data.view$favtime <- data.fav$time[Indices] 

#only keep rows in which time is greater than fav.time:
data.view <- data.view[data.view$time>data.view$favtime & !is.na(data.view$favtime),]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can combine the two data frames, group by `user` and `item` and then keep only `event` rows in `data.view` that occur after a `fav`. We use `cumsum` to count up instances of `fav` and select all rows from the first instance of `fav` onward.

The first set of code is for illustration, so you can see what the method is doing. The second set of code does the filtering directly.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.favorite %>% bind_rows(data.view) %>%
  arrange(user, item, time) %>%
  group_by(user, item) %>%
  mutate(sequence = cumsum(event=="fav"))
```

> ```
>     user  item  time event sequence
> 1      1     A     1  view        0
> 2      1     A     2   fav        1
> 3      1     A     3  view        1
> 4      1     B     4  view        0
> 5      1     B     5  view        0
> 6      1     B     6   fav        1
> 7      1     B     7  view        1
> 8      1     C     8  view        0
> 9      2     D     9   fav        1
> 10     3     A     2  view        0
> 11     3     A     5   fav        1
> 12     3     A     9  view        1
> ```

```
data.favorite %>% bind_rows(data.view) %>%
  arrange(user, item, time) %>%
  group_by(user, item) %>%
  filter(cumsum(event=="fav") >= 1, event=="view")
```

> ```
>    user  item  time event
> 1     1     A     3  view
> 2     1     B     7  view
> 3     3     A     9  view
> ```

Answer (score 1):

i would join by `user` and `item`, assuming that every user-item pair occurs only once in data.favorite. you can then directly compare viewtime with the time an item was favourited and discard all instances where time_viewed < time_favorited:

```
data.view %>%
left_join(data.favorite, by=c("user", "item"), suffix=c("_view","_fav")) %>%
filter(time_view > time_fav)
```

ETA: that was before i learned about the 'non-equi joins' @Henrik mentions in the comments above. Those sound cool.